Cast failing when generic type is a struct - gets wrapped into a nullable forsome reason
I've been banging my head on this one since yesterday, so any insights or outlook would be very welcome. I have the following code:
[StronglyTypedId(Template.Guid)]
public partial struct Invoice2Id;

public interface IQueryHandler
{
    //...
}

public interface IQueryHandler<T>: IQueryHandler
{
    //...
}

internal class ListQueryHandler<T>: IQueryHandler<IReadOnlyList<T>>, IQueryHandler<IEnumerable<T>>,
    IMaybeStatefulHandler where T : notnull
{
    private readonly ISqlFragment? _statement;

    public ListQueryHandler(ISqlFragment? statement, ISelector<T> selector)
    {
        _statement = statement;
        Selector = selector;
    }

//Some additional code not being relevant
}


public class MyClass<TOuter> where TOuter : notnull
{

   public IQueryHandler<TResult> BuildHandler<TResult>(ISomeSession session, ISqlFragment statement, ISqlFragment currentStatement)
   {
           return (IQueryHandler<TResult>)new ListQueryHandler<TOuter>(statement, this);
   }
}

And for some reason, when BuildHandler is called with the type Invoice2Id like below:
BuildHandler<Invoice2Id>(session, statement, currentStatement)
The cast to IQueryHandler fails with an Invalid cast exception. Apparently the struct is wrapped into a Nullable such that the following cast is attempted:
MyCode.Linq.QueryHandlers.IQueryHandler<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<System.Nullable<ValueTypeTests.StrongTypedId.Invoice2Id>>>

I suspect that this is what is causing the exception. The casts works fine if I replace the generic constraint TOuter : notnull with the constraint TOuter : struct (which was the original code), however my goal is to add support for arbitrary reference types, not just structs.
What's going on with this cast and how can I fix this issue?
I'd welcome any idea or insights,
Many thanks

The question isn't an exact duplicate but the root cause is the same so both answers apply to this one as well.

@ZoharPeled I'm perplexed, my code compiles fine, the error only takes place at runtime so I'm not sure the situations are exactly the same

I'll study the answer though since it indeed seems close, thanks for the pointer

Perhaps I was too fast on the duplicate button. Give it a good read and if you still think it's not a good duplicate ping me here and I'll retract my duplicate vote.
